# Android Navigation Drawer(DrawerLayout) is hidden by content view

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a `Navigation Drawer` issue.
On my Navigation Drawer app, sometimes Drawer is displayed behind the other content view. So only the part of the drawer is shown (the other parts are hidden by content area).

I tried everything but it does not works.

```
    drawer.bringToFront();
    drawer.buildLayer();
    drawer.clearFocus();
    drawer.requestLayout();
    drawer.forceLayout();
```

But in this situation, if I touch option button or change focus, screen is refreshed and it displays drawer well.
So I want to know what kinds of methods are called when I touch option button. Then I think I can call that method when drawer is opened.

Thank you so much in advanced.

Comment: Post the layout XML file which includes your main content view and the navigation drawer.

Comment: @Squonk, sorry. I can not upload XML, the app is commercialized one and consist of many views :(

Comment: Unless you post relevant code / layout files to reproduce the problem then nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting a sample code try to check with your code.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tile_image_data" >


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="48dip" >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#19000000"
        android:background="@drawable/tile_image_data"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by changing `android:id` in the `FrameLayout` from `@android:id/content` to `@+id/content`. Apparently it's not always a good idea to use system resource ids.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When the main view called onWindowsFocusChange() the drawer opened behind the main view. This happened with a Unity3D view.
I've solved the issue calling in the function
 `onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)` 
,which is a method inside the DrawerListener, drawerView.bringToFront().

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but it seems that it just only happen on versions prior KITKAT. Thanks to @jack, after I updated the code following, it is ok:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                drawerView.bringToFront();
                getWindow().getDecorView().requestLayout();
                getWindow().getDecorView().invalidate();
            }
        }
    };
```

You may want to know why do I invoke requestLayout() and invalidate(), just see the doc for bringToFront().